# Can't convert xml files to csv in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, object-detection

In order to use the tensorflow detection API i need to convert my xml files into csv labels. I used this code, taken from datitran's raccoon detection model. He has it on his github, give it a try. https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset

However, when I use his xml_to_csv code, I can compile it but the new label files are empty. Here is the code,

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
xml_list = []
for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for member in root.findall('object'):
        value = (root.find('filename').text,
                 int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                 int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                 member[0].text,
                 int(member[4][0].text),
                 int(member[4][1].text),
                 int(member[4][2].text),
                 int(member[4][3].text)
                 )
        xml_list.append(value)
column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
return xml_df


def main():
for directory in ['train','test']:
    image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images/{}'.format(directory))
    xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
    xml_df.to_csv('data/{}_labels.csv'.format(directory), index=None)
    print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

where 'train' and 'test' are the folders with xml files, images is the folder where they are contained and data is the folder where I want the labels files to be saved.

Comment: This worked for me! I was using the original code. Didn't work. But after making some corrections (as above by @Martin), I was able to convert.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the link given above to download the github repo and looked at the code.
Firstly, I copied the code above and pasted in a new file and ran it.

In the code posted above, The reason for you getting empty files is the `path` you're setting for the method to be called doesn't exist in the repo,

and if I assume that you want to use the `xml` files available in the `annotations` folder to create new `csv` files to contain test and train data separately, all you've got to do is to create two new directories called `test` and `train` in `Images` directory and copy the `xml` files from `annotations` to these new directories you have created and then you run the above code, it then works perfectly

I just did the same and copied only a few of the `xml` files from `annotations` directory
and while I'm at it, printed the dataframe to show

```
 F:\expts\raccoon_dataset-master\raccoon_dataset-master>python import.py
          filename  width  height    class  xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax
0    raccoon-1.png    650     417  raccoon    81    88   522   408
1   raccoon-10.png    450     495  raccoon   130     2   446   488
2   raccoon-11.png    660     432  raccoon     3     1   461   431
3   raccoon-12.png    259     194  raccoon    28    21   126   181
4   raccoon-12.png    259     194  raccoon    85    33   235   193
5   raccoon-13.png    660     495  raccoon    55    28   393   313
6   raccoon-14.png    900     484  raccoon   163    81   546   438
7   raccoon-15.png    640     360  raccoon   313    61   614   360
8    raccoon-2.png    800     573  raccoon    60    51   462   499
9    raccoon-3.png    720     480  raccoon     1     1   720   476
10   raccoon-4.png    275     183  raccoon    21    11   200   183
11   raccoon-5.png    270     187  raccoon     3     3   260   179
12   raccoon-6.png    480     360  raccoon     1    44   307   316
13   raccoon-7.png    410     308  raccoon    92    79   271   264
14   raccoon-8.png    259     194  raccoon    16    11   236   175
15   raccoon-9.png    347     510  raccoon    10     7   347   471
Successfully converted xml to csv.
         filename  width  height    class  xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax
0  raccoon-16.png    424     640  raccoon    51   178   355   632
1  raccoon-17.png    259     194  raccoon    95    60   167   118
2  raccoon-18.png    240     156  raccoon    32    25   201   130
3  raccoon-19.png    259     194  raccoon    87     8   182    89
4  raccoon-20.png    720     540  raccoon     2    29   720   503
5  raccoon-21.png    290     174  raccoon    59     2   216   171
6  raccoon-22.png    640     360  raccoon   252    76   466   335
7  raccoon-23.png    259     194  raccoon   108     1   258   194
8  raccoon-24.png    268     188  raccoon    77    48   179   156
9  raccoon-24.png    268     188  raccoon   139    77   202   145
Successfully converted xml to csv.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I do not use the whole raccoon repo,I am making my own model for a different detection, I just want to use a file to convert my xml files to csv ones. The path that I set is the path to the images in my directory, everything is correct. Also I have both the test and train folders in my directory but still thank you for the response :)

Comment: Oh, you should've made it clearer. Anyway, if you have the `xml` files in you test and train directories, your code should run perfectly

Comment: I do have them, but it doesn't... if only I could send you a pic to prove it hahaha

Answer (score 0):

lol im a bit late on this but I want to answer in case anyone else will encounter the issue. for me the issue was that os didn't find the path to the XML files, so I put the whole file directory in the part: "image_path = os.path.join( etc. etc..)"